# AngularJs filter throwing error in console TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to use custom filter in angularjs. The filter is working but its throwing errors in console.

Console:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
at Scope.<anonymous> (http://127.0.0.1:8080/static/restapi/js/refine.js:216:20)
at fnInvoke (http://127.0.0.1:8080/static/restapi/lib/angular/angular.js:10033:21)
at OPERATORS.| (http://127.0.0.1:8080/static/restapi/lib/angular/angular.js:9548:59)
at extend.constant (http://127.0.0.1:8080/static/restapi/lib/angular/angular.js:9978:14)
at Object.$watchCollectionWatch (http://127.0.0.1:8080/static/restapi/lib/angular/angular.js:11658:22)
at Scope.$digest (http://127.0.0.1:8080/static/restapi/lib/angular/angular.js:11822:40)
at Scope.$apply (http://127.0.0.1:8080/static/restapi/lib/angular/angular.js:12083:24)
at done (http://127.0.0.1:8080/static/restapi/lib/angular/angular.js:7841:45)
at completeRequest (http://127.0.0.1:8080/static/restapi/lib/angular/angular.js:8042:7)
at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onreadystatechange (http://127.0.0.1:8080/static/restapi/lib/angular/angular.js:7985:11) angular.js:9435(anonymous function) angular.js:9435

TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
at Scope.<anonymous> (http://127.0.0.1:8080/static/restapi/js/refine.js:216:20)
at fnInvoke (http://127.0.0.1:8080/static/restapi/lib/angular/angular.js:10033:21)
at OPERATORS.| (http://127.0.0.1:8080/static/restapi/lib/angular/angular.js:9548:59)
at extend.constant (http://127.0.0.1:8080/static/restapi/lib/angular/angular.js:9978:14)
at Object.$watchCollectionWatch (http://127.0.0.1:8080/static/restapi/lib/angular/angular.js:11658:22)
at Scope.$digest (http://127.0.0.1:8080/static/restapi/lib/angular/angular.js:11822:40)
at Scope.$apply (http://127.0.0.1:8080/static/restapi/lib/angular/angular.js:12083:24)
at c (http://127.0.0.1:8080/static/restapi/js/ng-infinite-scroll.min.js:2:595)
at http://127.0.0.1:8080/static/restapi/js/ng-infinite-scroll.min.js:2:801
at http://127.0.0.1:8080/static/restapi/lib/angular/angular.js:13609:28 angular.js:9435
```

This is the code:

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">

<center>
 <form>
  <input ng-model="searchString" type="text">
  <button ng-click="go('/search/'+searchString)">Search</button>
 </form>

 <h1>Results</h1> 
<div ng-controller='DemoController'>
 <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="i in websites | searchFor:searchString">
    <a href="/website/{{i.domain_name}}" ><h3>{{i.domain_name}}</h3></a>
    </li>
 </ul>
</div>
</center>
</div>
```

app.js

```
myApp.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams','$location','$filter',
 function($scope, $routeParams,$location,$filter) {

$scope.searchString=$routeParams.q;
$scope.go = function (path) {
$location.path(path);
};
}]);

//In websitesSvc I use angular services to get data using $http

myApp.controller('DemoController', ['$scope','websitesSvc',
function($scope,websitesSvc) {

    websitesSvc.getwebsites().then(function(websites){
        $scope.websites = websites;
})}
]);


myApp.filter('searchFor', function(){

return function(websites, searchString){

    if(!searchString){
        return 0;
    }

    var result = [];

    searchString = searchString.toLowerCase();

    console.log(websites.length); //showing the array length here in console

    var len = websites.length;   //Error in console in this line

    var i =0;
    for(i=0;i<len;i++){
        if(websites[i].domain_name.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchString) !== -1){
            result.push(websites[i]);
         }  
    };
    return result;  //Results are shown on HTML page it works
};
});
```

When I `console.log(websites.length)` it gives the no. of objects in console.Also its returning the values.How to debug this error ?

Comment: can you put plunker for this?

Comment: I have added more information to make question more clear.I am using services to get data from django rest framework api so their is no json file.I don't know if without data can I put plunker as arrays get data from api using service.Can you please see the code now hope the added info makes the question clear

Comment: The error says websites is not defined. If console.log works, probably you have 2 same elements of websites in the codes, perhaps in your factory?

Comment: Is it possible it's trying to get the length of the object before it's being loaded in?

Comment: @Aarmora I have mentioned in the question, when I console.log(websites.length) it gives the no. of objects in console. So I don't think there's any issue with the load time